# I want to add more data to a existing tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I tried `load_model` and then `model.fit` method to load a existing model and adding some more data on it. It seems working. Epoch also worked without any issue. But after saving the new trained model it looks like the old model. Exactly same file size, same data. What I am doing wrong?

```
from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model('/content/drive/MyDrive/Trained_database/diu_project.h5')
model.fit(x=X_train, y=y_train, epochs=30, batch_size = 5,shuffle = False, validation_split=0.2)
model.save('/content/drive/MyDrive/Trained_database/diu_project_3.h5')
```

Comment: When you diff the files are they actually exactly the same? You should expect the file sizes to be the same, and likely the headers to be identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check if the layers of the model you are loading are trainable?

```
model.summary()
```

Is the number of trainable parameters what you would expect? You can make all the layers trainable with the following code:

```
model.trainable = True
```

Or train only from a certain layer (let's say number 100). This is particularly useful for transfer learning between close domains.

```
# Fine-tune from this layer onwards
fine_tune_at = 100

# Freeze all the layers before the `fine_tune_at` layer
for layer in base_model.layers[:fine_tune_at]:
  layer.trainable =  False
```

The examples are from:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning